# youtube api music only filter

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to filter only music videos with the api.

I have looked on the youtube api(v3) website but cant find it.

```
try {
        // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
        // query term.
        $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
            'q' => $_GET['q'],
            'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
            'type' => 'video',
            **'videoCategoryId' => 'Music',**
        ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `videoCategoryID` for `music` is `10`. You can see this here:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

So you code ends up looking like this:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
    'q' => $_GET['q'],
    'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    'type' => 'video',
    'videoCategoryId' => '10'
));
```

Here is a quick and dirty way to get the full list of categories:

```
<?php

$ids = implode(",", range(1,50));

$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=" . $ids . "&key={YOUR-API-KEY}");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);

foreach ($json_data['items'] as $category) {
    echo $category['id'] . ' = ' . $category['snippet']['title'] . '<br/>';
}

?>
```